# Multiple DataTemplates in ListView.Resources with inheritance?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, win-universal-app

So I have a ListView with multiple DataTemplates, but I am not sure if this is the right way to do this. My XAML looks like this:

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ParentClass" x:DataType="local:ParentClass">
        <!-- The Template -->
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ChildClass" x:DataType="local:ChildClass">
        <!-- The Template -->
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.Resources>
```

And my classes look like this:

```
class ParentClass {}
class ChildClass: ParentClass {}
```

How can I be sure that this will take the `ParentClass` template only when the object is not a `ChildClass`? Do I need to put them in a special order? Is this not possible with XAML and do I need to create a second "dummy" child class to avoid the problem altogether?

Comment: You you to implement DataTemplateSelector. refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747924/wp-8-1-datatemplateselector-isnt-working

Comment: I found that it doesn't matter. It uses the most specialized template it can, without regard to order of definition.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, if you can find a source for that, you may post it as an answer and I will accept it.